# body mass is not changed using box2d cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

i just cant figure out how this mass thing works .
i have read the box2d docs, (which have many commands that are not in the cocos2d at the moment) and i was trying to understand the mass thing.

i know that if i change the body density it doesnt change a thing :

```
    //add body
b2BodyDef spriteBodyDef;
spriteBodyDef.type =b2_dynamicBody; //b2_staticBody;
spriteBodyDef.position.Set(pilot1.position.x/PTM_RATIO,pilot1.position.y/PTM_RATIO);
spriteBodyDef.userData = pilot1;
pilot1Body = world->CreateBody(&spriteBodyDef);    
b2CircleShape spriteShape; //b2polygon-for box shape
spriteShape.m_radius = 15.0/PTM_RATIO;
b2FixtureDef spriteShapeDef;
spriteShapeDef.restitution = 0.4f;
spriteShapeDef.shape = &spriteShape;
//spriteShapeDef.density=10.0f;

b2Fixture *fix=pilot1Body->GetFixtureList();
fix->SetDensity(1.5f);
pilot1Body->ResetMassData();
NSLog(@"mass2: %f", pilot1Body->GetMass());  
spriteShapeDef.isSensor = false;
pilot1Body->CreateFixture(&spriteShapeDef);
    [self addChild:pilot1];
```

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set new density for some or all the fixtures attached to the body using `b2Fixture::SetDensity` and then call `b2Body::ResetMassData`, for example:

```
    NSLog(@"mass1: %f", body->GetMass());
    b2Fixture *fix = body->GetFixtureList();
    while (fix) {
        fix->SetDensity(1.5f);
        fix = fix->GetNext();
    }
    body->ResetMassData();
    NSLog(@"mass2: %f", body->GetMass());
```

Comment: thanks but i have done that: spriteShapeDef.density = 0.0;
 pilot1Body->ResetMassData();  and i was playing with the density from 0 to 200 but it does not change a THING. what am i missing here ?

Comment: @Rant, did you try my code or not? my code does not modify shapeDef's density, it directly modifies the density of the fixtures. (remember that fixture def, shape def, anything-def are only used when creating fixture, shape, anything and modifying the def after the objects are created won't change the objects' properties)

Comment: i did what you said- please see my edit of the question to see what i did . thanks .

Comment: i get crash on the setdensity when doing this.